# What is the HTTP command to send usernames and passwords to a Web Server?

Tags: c++, http, authentication

I have tried the GET and POST Methods I've looked at tons of resources, but still can't figure out the HTTP command to send passwords and usernames to a server to get authenticated. I know I've asked a similar question, and got RFC 2016 as the answer. But it still need more help. Here is my HTTP message, I'm sending right now...

```
string m = "POST " +  URI " / " + "HTTP/1.1" + "\n" + 
"Host:" + Cite + "\n" +
"Authorization:" + " " + "Basic" + " " + username + ":" + password;
```

Oh and does anybody know the response message if the password is incorrect, I think it looks something like the following, but I'm really unsure.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Logon Failed
```

Answer (score 2):

You are quite close: The concatenation of username, ":" and password must be encoded in base64 before putting it into the header. For example to login "user" with password "pass" you would send

```
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzCg==
```

**Edit:**

The response will always look like

```
HTTP/v.v NNN some text
```

with `v.v` being the HTTP version **actually used** (a.o.t. requested, though mostly the same), `NNN` being the result code and `some text` being a textual representation of the result code.

While the result code (e.g. 401 for unauthorized) is constant, the textual representation is only informational and might be different on various systems.

Comment: Ya but the thing is I already made a function to send the username and password encrypted and I keep getting an error from winsock saying the data couldn't be sent to the server, I think it might be because I'm sending the password to the dvma page hosted on my localhost

Comment: HTTP basic authorization knows nothing about encrypted passwords. They are always sent in base64

Comment: Do I have encrypt the username and password into base64 or does the server do it for me

Comment: base64 is no encryption, but an encoding. The server expects base64, so you have to send base64, meaning you have to do it before you create and send your buffer. See my example!